# Batch inserts with @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

In my spring application i want to insert almost 1500 records in database in one go. I am using Spring 4.X and plain hibernate in backend. In my service layer i use @Transactional annotation. Now while inserting the records after somepoint i get outofmemory error. After searching on internet i found out that we can use something similar to this

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

However, above code they are using sessionFactory and transaction manually and use flush and clear on session object and do i a manual commit.

In my case i do not want to use above code, i want to use @Transactional annotation to make this work.

Please suggest

I do not want to use session factory and transaction object manually. ....@transactional should do it all

Comment: What is your spring xml configuration?

Comment: Just remove the session handing (use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession` and leave the `flush` and `clear`.

Comment: Does that mean that in my code i have to compulsoriy use sessionFactory manually ? Cant i just use @Transactional annotation?

Comment: If i am using Session and Transaction manually then using @Transactional in application is of no use...

Comment: Did you get any answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want change from BMT(Bean Managment Transaction) to CMT (Container Transaction Managment), your snippet on code will became:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveCustomers(){
    for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    }
}
```

The container will flush all entities when the method will end. Now I want to ask you, Why Do you nees to need each 20 entities?

Comment: If you need to ask the question I strongly suggest a read on how hibernate works, especially with regards to caching and dirty checking.

Comment: You may want to flush periodically to avoid keeping all 100000 customer instances in hibernate first level cache.

Comment: Correct , but in that case do i need to compulsorily use SessionFactory and Transaction object manually. in case of @Transactional annotation it does commit /rollback internally