# Using @Transactional for batch inserts

Tags: database, spring, hibernate

In my spring application, I am using Spring 4.X and Plain hibernate in back end. I have to do batch inserts of Customer objects.But After sometime i get out of memory error.I am using spring's declarative transaction i.e `@Transactional` annotation at service layer. How can i do the batch inserts in this case.

Code

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager",readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)

public Customer add(CustomerForm customerForm, Errors errors, MultipartFile photo)

{
```

Edited

**i don't want to use sessionFactory and session of manually. and FYI i use hibernate template in backend. –**

Comment: Welcome to SO. The code snippet you supplied is a bit short, don't you think?

Comment: From service layer i call dao which uses hibernateTemplate to insert the data

Comment: Posting the code for saving in DAO layer will be helpful.

Comment: hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(customer);

Comment: this question is **highly** similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/33911741/2257772

Comment: even though the posts are similar no solution is provided